# Each network operation causes sound interference

Tags: networking, windows-10, audio, ipv6

Recently I found that each network operation (like opening web pages in browser or loading old ones) causes sound corrupt (digital interference) in listening music or watching video (with sound).

Music should not be streamed remotely, i.e. local played music is also corrupt.

This can't be related with network bandwidth directly, because torrent can work at high speed (but sound is corrupting very much when torrent is working).

Also there is no apparent relation with CPU load, because it is apparent low.

The problem may relate with proxy and/or IPv6 protocol disabling.

Does anybody met with similar problems?

May be this is somehow related with drivers?

Comment: Sound distortion, crackling, humming, or whatever you want to call the noise, is usually caused by hardware.  Is the sound plugged into the motherboard or sound card?  If you closely inspect the motherboard/sound card, are there any capacitors with a bulging or open top?  Those are the cylinders that sometimes have an X at the top (from the indention in the metal).  Worst case, there could be an issue on the motherboard that causes the interference, but I would start by finding out which piece of hardware is causing the problem. Just to note, I would check the motherboard, because of the NIC.

Comment: How capacitors can explain relation with network activity?

Comment: If both the sound and NIC you are using is on the motherboard, then there's a high chance electrical damage to the motherboard is causing the interference. For example, my brother had a similar problem on an old Dell computer, but in his case it was so extreme that sound only came out as a crackling noise. When he switched to a sound card, it worked perfectly. When checking his motherboard, there were blown capacitors all over his motherboard, which is a good indicator of damage on the board. If you don't have any visual indicators, then it gets harder to troubleshoot without replacing parts.

Comment: Currently I got some apparently unrelated NTFS problem with `hiberfil.sys`, rebooted with disk fixing, and the problem is gone... Don't know if it was the reason, but the problem is definitely not manifestating for now.

Comment: Well, I would keep that in mind next time you check your motherboard.  If it's electrical, it may be intermittent, but hopefully it doesn't come back.

Comment: Though the subject would appear to be at first glance totally unrelated, I just finished this answer which explains **how** it happens. - http://superuser.com/questions/1064677/ghost-image-of-monitor-1-in-monitor-2-with-wound-together-vga-cables _ & why people are asking you to check for electrical failure; blown capacitors, ground loops etc.